# Types cannot be provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name parameter is set to true in lumen with elastic search 7.6.2

Tags: php, elasticsearch, lumen, elasticsearch-7

I am using https://github.com/basemkhirat/elasticsearch package.

In **es.php** file i have below **indices**

```
'indices' => [
        'media' => [
            'settings' => [
                'number_of_shards' => 2,
                'number_of_replicas' => 2,
                'analysis' => [
                    'filter' => [
                        'custom_english_stemmer' => [
                            'type' => "stemmer",
                            'name' => "english"
                        ],
                        "english_stop" => [
                            'type' => "stop",
                            'stopwords' => "_english_"
                        ]
                    ],
                    "analyzer" => [
                        'custom_lowercase_analyzer' => [
                            // 'type' => 'custom',
                            'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                            'filter' => [
                                'lowercase',
                                'english_stop',
                                "custom_english_stemmer"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'mappings' => [
                'properties' => [
                    'id' => [
                        'type' => 'long',
                        'index' => false,
                        'doc_values' => false,
                    ],
                    'title' => [
                        'type' => 'text',
                        "analyzer" => 'custom_lowercase_analyzer'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Now when `php artisan es:indices:create` is executed settings is created but mapping fails with an error message.

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Types cannot be provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name parameter is set to true."
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Types cannot be provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name parameter is set to true."
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

[image]

How to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing type in your create index code, remove `media` type from your index, as types are deprecated, see [the removal of types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/removal-of-types.html) for more information.

Please note in Elasticsearch 7.X still you can do some workaround to have custom `types` by having `include_type_name` param but it's not preferred as `types` will be totally removed in upcoming Elasticsearch 8.X.

In order to use create your index with custom `type` like `media`(default is `_doc` mentioned in your screen-shot) in your case, you need to pass `include_type_name=true` to index creation, template, and mappings APIs as mentioned in [this official ES blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/moving-from-types-to-typeless-apis-in-elasticsearch-7-0)

Comment: if i remove `media` then how do i create multiple indexes basically **media** was my index name

Comment: removing `media` will give  `Undefined index: settings`

Comment: @Sharath, you can give index name in create index request as part of URL please see how to create index in ES 7.X which is your version https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html

Comment: @Sharath please see this index request where both setting and mapping mentioned https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#mappings please note index name is in URL and not in body

Comment: yes through api it works only this is that through php from the library which i am using is failing so wanted to about it...  well i tried the same thing in kibana it works well..

Comment: @Sharath, sorry didn't get you

Comment: like what ever you see within `media` array in php code i.e., settings and mappings, trying to run this in kibana or through api will work.. same structure through php code fails with above error